# Javascript iterated inner values of Array/Object with the same key

Tags: javascript, node.js

Am building a nodejs app and it has very many clients with different timezones. I save all the data in Unix time stamp, when a client logs in i use the clients timezone to add or subtract to the unix time stamp stored in the database, so that it matches the clients time.

The user data (a document/object), has keys with Arrays and other objects aswell,

```
{
 name: "data",
 location": "us",
 activity: [],
 time: 1476301165252,
 subdoc: [{
          time: 1476301165252,
          someotherKeys: ....
         }]

}
```

How can i loop through this document and edit all the "time" keys(including inner objects and arrays aswell) and add or subtract a number to all "time" keys respectively.

The number will be uniform. meaning all the "time" keys will be iterated with the same number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use a recursive `for...in` loop to solve this, I think.

Something like this:

```
function changeTime (inputObj, newTimeVal) {
    var key;
    for (key in inputObj) {
        if (key === "time") {
            inputObj[key] = newTimeVal;
        }
        if (typeof inputObj[key] === 'object') {
            changeTime(inputObj[key], newTimeVal);
        }
    }
}
```

Might not be exactly right, but it should get you on the right path.

edit:
If you only want to add or subtract from the original value, it's easy enough to use this same pattern:

```
function changeTime (inputObj, delta) { // we'll always add here-- you can pass in a negative or positive number to account for add or subtract
    var key;
    for (key in inputObj) {
        if (key === "time") {
            inputObj[key] = inputObj[key] + delta;
        }
        if (typeof inputObj[key] === 'object') {
            changeTime(inputObj[key], delta);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I only want to add or subtract from the current value,

Comment: Objects in JS are passed by reference-- you're editing the same object you passed in.

Comment: Check out this example data https://jsfiddle.net/grnxex31/ . Your method  only outputs the edited keys, can you make your method return the same object together with keys changed.

Comment: @Tuna -- I think you are misunderstanding what is happening.  When you pass an object or an array into a method, the method isn't editing a copy like a primitive-- it is _editing the same object you passed in_.  My method doesn't return anything because it is editing the object you passed in directly-- that's how objects are passed in JS.  Try console logging the value of `userData` before you pass it into the method, and then logging its value _after_ it has been passed in-- I think you will see that `userData` has been updated/transformed after my function completes.

Comment: Please see [this section of the MDN reference on functions for details](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions#Description) for details-- it clearly states "...object references are values, too, and they are special: if the function changes the referred object's properties, that change is visible outside the function..."

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
    var obj = {
        name: "data",
        location: "us",
        activity: [],
        time: 1476301165252,
        subdoc: [{
            time: 1476301165252,
        }]

    };

function iterate(obj) {
    for (var property in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
            if (typeof obj[property] == "object") {
                iterate(obj[property], property);
            } else {
                if (property === 'time') {
                    console.log(property + "   " + obj[property]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

iterate(obj)
```

https: //jsfiddle.net/uxqgd8cf/

Comment: Your method only outputs the edited "time" keys, can you make that method return the same object together with the edited keys.

Comment: if (property === 'time') {
 console.log(property + "   " + obj[property]);
} , inside this you can edit the time... which would update the orginal object...

Comment: Yes it works, look at a real example with my user data, it doesn't return the whole object https://jsfiddle.net/1gmx3kk0/

Comment: your object is getting modified... check this one... look where i have placed my console.log statement and inside my if block i am updating the property value... https://jsfiddle.net/1gmx3kk0/1/

Answer (score -1):

You have to use for in loop to loop objects in Javascript 
https://www.google.com.tr/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in&ved=0ahUKEwiJ7q6WhtbPAhUkAsAKHXehDAkQFggaMAA&usg=AFQjCNGzYTP9ERuhLVoFVYR52HohZmZ0eQ&sig2=N_sNA5ZjKyeVmCjEisDNDQ

Comment: Can you please share some example code in context of my question